# Best library for protocol handling in Java?

Tags: java, network-protocols, protocol-buffers, java-io

I have a device attached to a serial port and using a specific protocol to interact with it.
I need to write a parser for write/read the protocol message according to a given message format.

Basically I need to serialize/deserialize objects to and from stream using a given format.

I'm wondering if there are any good java library made specific for this purpose, on top of the Java.IO? Bear in mind that the protocol is running through a serial port so it can be slow.

I have read google's protocolbuffer, sounds a very promising solution, but it looks  has its own serialisation format, which I canot use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly why does it matter exactly how some object is serialized ? If the library provides readers and writers for both ends then why worry about it. On the other hand if you have some other system which is not java based that also wants to read/write that format then you have a problem.

All serialization libraries introduce their own format

- java serialization
- protocol buffers
- your favourite xml binding framework
- thrift
- jboss serialization

If both ends can use the library then pick the one that is best based on runtime characteristics such as

- speed ... faster is better
- size ... less is better
- compression - might be important
- security/encryption might be necessary if you want secure the layer under it.
- versioning to support evolving of messages as the app grows...(thanx MG)

Comment: I would propose that the "versioning" story is another important one for the list

Comment: Because the message format is already defined and used in the hardware. It is not possible to use any of the above. But i'm still interested in any library that can, say, according to a format definition, generate the required formatted message, and  be able to parse it back. That will help a lot on the tedious parsing work normally need to do.